# disable image download on android browser

Tags: android, mobile-webkit

how do I disable the functionality on Android browsers where a user can press and hold and image and bring up a "save image" popup dialog.

for ios devices, `-webkit-touch-callout:none;` works, but this seems to have no effect on android browsers

Answer (score 0):

attach an event handler for the click event which calls event.preventDefault(). At least this did work for me when using ICS´ default web browser, chrome beta and opera mobile.